# SCILAB ode: How to solve 2nd order ODE

Tags: scilab

I am coming from ode45 in MATLAB trying to learn ode in scilab. I ran into an exception I am not sure how to address.

```
function der = f(t,x)
    wn3 = 2800 * %pi/30; //rad/s
    m = 868.1/32.174; //slugs
    k = m*wn3^2; //lbf/ft
    w = 4100 * %pi/30; //rad/s
    re_me = 4.09/32.174/12; //slug-ft
    F0 = w^2*re_me; //lbf

    der(1) = x(2);
    der(2) = -k*x(1) + F0*sin(w*t);
endfunction

x0 = [0; 0];
t = 0:0.1:5;
t0 = t(1);
x = ode(x0,t0,t,f);
plot(t,x(1,:));
```

I get this error message that I don't understand:

```
lsoda--  at t (=r1), mxstep (=i1) steps   
needed before reaching tout
      where i1 is :        500                                                  
      where r1 is :   0.1027287737654D+01                                       
Excessive work done on this call (perhaps wrong jacobian type).
at line    35 of executed file C:\Users\ndomenico\Documents\Scilab\high_frequency_vibrator_amplitude_3d.sce

ode: lsoda exit with state -1.
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ode is particularly stiff (k = 2319733). To me, it has no sense to give such a large final time. The time step you took (0.1) is also very large w.r.t to the driving frequency. If you replace the line

```
t = 0:0.1:5
```

by

```
t = linspace(0,0.1,1001)
```

i.e. request approximations of your solution for t in [0,0.1] and 1000 time steps you will have the following output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you! that makes sense. I didn't think about the stiffness being an issue